# increasing number in xpath selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

so I have this kind of xpaths:

```
html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]
```

then

```
html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]
```

then

```
html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]
```

etc..

as you can see, the only number that is being increased is the second on the right div[1], div[2], div[3]

And I need to make actions with 100's of this kind of xpaths.
Are there any possibility, for example, to save it to variable and just add 1 to the actual number, and for example run it in **for loop**?

so my program would pick all of those 3 xpaths automatically.

Thanks for all replies! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a straightforward use of a for loop using `range()`:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    xpath = f'html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[{i}]/div[1]'
    # now do something with xpath
```

Comment: Thanks John. I am not an pro with python, but look:     for i in range(1, 101):
        xpath = f'html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[{i}]/div[1]'
        xpath.click()  

- this is how it looks. and it says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

how to click on this xpath?

Comment: You have to pass that xpath value to selenium's find by xpath function.  That's what I meant by the "now do something with xpath" comment.  Your question seemed to only ask how to generate xpath values, so that is the only area I addressed.